# Is there an easier way to reference Bootstrap files in a master page after installing through NuGet?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, nuget-package

Is there an easier way to reference Bootstrap/jQuery files in a master page after installing through NuGet without manually referencing the files?

Comment: You can just drag and drop the file into your .cshtml master page. Do you means something else?

Comment: Drag and dropping the files (style sheets/javascript) is what I'm doing now.) I was hoping for a shortcut that did that for me and maybe I wasn't aware of it. I guess not.

Comment: You can make partial view which contain your script and stylesheet files. you can simply render to masters page you want. You have a lot of master page or you need to put stylesheet and js file on all the .cshtml files